# How to hot reload classes in JBoss

Tags: java, deployment, jboss

I'm using JBoss AS 4.2.3.GA and I want to make it to hot reload changed classes.
Now, I have a running JBoss AS with deployed exploded war, after changing (recompiling) some classes, it starts to redeploy all war:

> 14:14:03,732 INFO  [StandardContext] Reloading this Context has started

and redeployment takes a very long time. I want to avoid such time wasting, and maybe there is a way to tell JBoss, just to replace changed class files w/o redeploying all the war?

I've also tried `reloadable="true"` in

> jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\deploy\jboss-web.deployer\server.xml

But, perhaps, that's not what i seek. I don't know if it matters, but the exploded war's directory is external to server's /default/deploy/ dir. All my classes are in WEB-INF/classes dir.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to research framework-specific solutions. Look for OSGi, Spring Dynamic Modules, JEE6 dependency injection.

Also, there may be an Eclipse plugin that will facilitate this for you. I know there is one for Glassfish and JEE6.

What technology are you developing this with?

Comment: I`m using Spring and JBoss Seam, IntelliJ IDE